# Bison grammar shift/reduce conflicts handling factorial along with other unary operators

Tags: bison, yacc

I'm noodling around with bison as I read a book on it, and I'm working on a simple infix calculator where I use the grammar to dictate precedence rather than using `%left/%right` and the order of such declarations.

Most bison calculators I've seen have factorial as a function rather than an operator so those examples have not been helpful.

Currently I have:

```
 15 calclist:
 16   | calclist expr EOL { printf(" = %d\n", $2); }
 17   | calclist EOL { /* nada */ }
 18   ;
 19 expr:
 20     term
 21   | expr '+' term { $$ = $1 + $3; }
 22   | expr '-' term { $$ = $1 - $3; }
 23   ;
 24 term:
 25     factor
 26   | term '*' factor { $$ = $1 * $3; }
 27   | term '/' factor { $$ = $1 / $3; }
 28   ;
 29 factor:
 30     '|' factor { $$ = $2 > 0 ? $2 : -$2; }
 31   | '-' factor { $$ = 0 - $2; }
 32   | '(' expr ')' { $$ = $2; }
 33   | '(' expr ')' '!' { $$ = factorial($2); }
 34   | NUMBER '!' { $$ = factorial($1); }
 35   | NUMBER
 36   ;
```

Lines 33 and 34 seem overly verbose.  I felt like the proper way to do this is replacing 33/34 with:

```
33   | factor '!' { $$ = factorial($1); }
```

But then I get shift/reduce conflicts with negation/abs value operators, which makes sense when I looked at the `calc.output` file generated with `bison -v`.

Is there a cleaner way to do this while maintaining the expr/term/factor grammar which defines the operator precedence?  Or is my working solution the best I can do given my constraints (self imposed or otherwise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does `-2!` mean? If you add `factor: factor '!'`, then you create an ambiguity because you could parse that as either `- <factor: 2 !>` or `<factor: - 2> !`, which are obviously semantically different. [Note 1]

I think the normal understanding would be that postfix operators such as <kbd>!</kbd> take precedence over any prefix operator, so that the natural interpretation of `-2!` as `-(2!)` should be applied. [Note 2]

So there has to be a precedence level which binds more tightly than unary prefix operators. And every time you introduce a new precedence level, you need to introduce a new corresponding non-terminal (unless you use precedence declarations; see the bison manual for details and examples).

That leads to:

```
expr:
    term
  | expr '+' term { $$ = $1 + $3; }
  | expr '-' term { $$ = $1 - $3; }
  ;
term:
  factor
  | term '*' factor { $$ = $1 * $3; }
  | term '/' factor { $$ = $1 / $3; }
  ;
factor:
    postfix
  | '|' postfix { $$ = $2 > 0 ? $2 : -$2; }
  | '-' postfix { $$ = 0 - $2; }
  ;
postfix:
    postfix '!'  { $$ = factorial($1); }
  | '(' expr ')' { $$ = $2; }
  | NUMBER
  ;
```

---

#### Notes

1. `(-2)!` might or might not be a semantic error but it doesn't seem like there is any possibility of making it a syntactic error, since the syntax cannot know what `(3-5)!` might be. Semantically, if one were to generalise factorial to the Euler gamma function, it would be meaningful for negative numbers, with the proviso that Γ of a negative *integer* is infinite. But that's a complete digression.
2. In languages like C which have postfix `++`, this rule is also normal; `-x++` means `-(x++)`. More commonly, the prefix operator in this case would be <kbd>*</kbd>.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the answer.  I was too hung up on the fact that -, |, ! are unary operators that I didn't consider going one level deeper specifically for !.  I suppose the reason why we have to bring parens down to that level is because they are of the highest precedence *and* we want to be able to apply factorial to an expression inside parens?

Comment: The precedence of parentheses is more complicated than that summary, but I presume that you do want to be able to factorial a parenthesized expression. You should think about a CFG as defining syntactic possibilities; "precedence" is a not-very-well-defined mental shortcut. `term: term '*' factor` is a declaration that what follows `*` does not derive from a production including `+` or `*`  (among others) while what precedes might derive from a `*` production but still not a `+`.

Comment: If you were to use precedence declarations instead of writing an unambiguous grammar, you would find that there is no need to declare the precedence of parentheses, because they create no conflicts. At least, not until you implement function calls, at which point you need to consider  `'(' params ')'` to be the syntactic equivalent of a postfix operator; the `(` would be in the same precedence group as `!`. With your grammar, the call syntax would go into the `postfix` productions.